How to integrate $\int\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx$?
How to integrate $$\int\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx$$ ?
I am trying to integrate this above expression by assuming the above integral to be $I$.
Therefore, $$I=\int\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx$$.
When $|x|=x$,
$$I=\int\frac{x+5}{x+8}dx$$
$\implies I=x-3\ln|x+8|+C$
When $|x|=-x$,
$$I=\int\frac{5-x}{8-x}dx$$
$\implies I=x+3\ln|8-x|+C_1$
But my doubt is how to solve this integral combining both the cases together in a single case? In R.S. AGGARWAL and R.D. SHARMA book this types of questions are solved generally by considering only the case $|x|=x$. But I can't understand why the book has ignored the case $|x|=-x$. Please help me out with this question.
Should we also consider the case $x=0$ ?

To combine both cases together in a single case, choose the constants $C,C_1$ such that the result of both parts is the same for $x=0$, i.e. $-3\ln8+C=3\ln8+C_1$, i.e. $C_1=C-6\ln8$, and define an indefinite integral $F$ on $\Bbb R$ by
$$F(x)=x+C+\begin{cases}-3\ln(x+8)&\text{if }x\ge0\\3\ln(8-x)-6\ln8&\text{if }x\le0.\end{cases}$$
This way, you obtain:
$$\forall a,b\in\Bbb R\quad\int_a^b\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx=F(b)-F(a).$$

As per your answer @Anne Bauval the answer of the $2^{nd}$ case will be $x+3\ln|8-x|-6\ln8$. But in Wolfram Alpha answer is given in a single case combining both the cases together.

Really? So what is WA's answer?

I didn't check with WA, but I'm going to put a bet down that they use the sign() function.

$\frac{1}{2}(-(sgn(x)-1)(x+3\log(x-8))+(sgn(x)+1)(x-3\log(x+8)+3i\pi+2\log(512)))$.

WA's answer which you reported is indeed, provided you remove their strange $3i\pi$, a way to combine the 2 cases in a single (but ugly) formula, corresponding to set $C=2\ln(512)=6\ln(8)$ in mine.

So, then how to integrate @AnneBauval?

I don't understand your question.

In Indefinite integral,  is it correct to mention  two cases, one for $x\geq 0$ and another one for $x<0$ @AnneBauval?

Does my edit answer your question? The integrand $\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}$ is defined and continuous on $\Bbb R$. Once $F$ has been defined on the whole $\Bbb R$ (either by cases or by a single formula using the sign function), one must not 'mention two cases'.

So, which case to consider @AnneBauval?

What do you mean 'which case'? both are used, to define $F$ on all of $\Bbb R$ by cases. Then when evaluating $F(b)-F(a)$, you consider, for each of $a$ and $b$, the case(s) corresponding to the respective sign(s) of $a$ and $b$.

Ok. I understood. Thank u @AnneBauval

If $x\ge 0$ the $I=x+\int\frac{-3}{x+8}dx= = x-3\ln|x+8|+C$
If $x<0$ then $I= x+\int\frac{-3}{8-x}dx= x+3\ln|8-x|+C$
Note that $\operatorname{sgn(x)} =1$ if $x\ge 0, \ \operatorname{sgn(x)} =-1$ if $x\le 0, \ \operatorname{sgn(x)} =0 $ if $x= 0 $ and with this we can combine the two cases
$$I = x +\frac{-3\ln|x+8|(\operatorname{sgn(x)}+1)}{2}-\frac{3\ln|8-x|(\operatorname{sgn(x)}-1)}{2}+C   $$

Here is another approach that I find interesting
$$\int\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx$$ Notice that the integrand is symmetric to the $y$ axis so we can write the integral as such $$\frac{x}{|x|}\int\frac{|x|}{x}\cdot \frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx=\frac{x}{|x|}\int\frac{|x|(|x|+5)}{x(|x|+8)} dx$$
This can be integrated by parts if we define $f=|x|+5 , g=\log(|x|+8)$ and $f'=\frac{x}{|x|} , g'=\frac{x}{|x|(|x|+8)} $.
$$\int fg'=fg-\int f'g \implies (|x|+5)\log(|x|+8)-\int\frac{x\log(|x|+8}{|x|}dx$$
Now let $u=|x|+8$ and $du=\frac{x}{|x|}$
$$\int\frac{x\log(|x|+8)}{|x|}dx=\int\log(u)=u\log(u)-u=(|x|+8)\log(|x|+8)-|x|-8$$
After simplifying we get
$$\int\frac{|x|+5}{|x|+8}dx=\frac{8x-3x\log(|x|+8)}{|x|}+C$$
